# PL/SQL Query works slow when execute on aspx.vb form

Tags: join, plsql

My PL/SQL query process slow in aspx.vb web forms whereas When the same query runs in PL/SQL it's fast. Please help if any suitable suggestion is there?

Comment: the additional time taken could be in establishing the db connection! what driver you use?

Comment: Sir I get the solution by myself :) actually previously Report generated on HTML page now I am using gridview.

Comment: How many rows are you returning?  If may be your vb code, not the sql statement.  Please show some code.

Comment: Rows is about 1000 records at a time. But its process ok Now. As I am using Gridview instead of HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options like sharing/pooling the db connection to the Oracle database, paging the results, avoid loops (read data, update ui, read more data, update ui) etc.

Please measure the time for:

1. creation the db connection
2. execute the query
3. update the ui
   (the datagrid in your case)

You can also try to limit or grow your data and see if the delay is related to the data size/row number.

Hope it help,

Pedro

Comment: Thanks Pedro Polonia... Now I am using Grid Previously I was getting a Slow response when executing the query because the resulting query values displayed on HTML Table on new page.Problem solved by Using GridView on my ASPX page.